# form (error: cannot find symbol )

Tags: java, scala, playframework, template-engine, helper

i am trying to implement helpers for my templates by this video

[Play! Framework 2.0 Tutorial Simple Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cm3zLB8Iuvw)

but stuck

```
package com.pack.controllers;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import play.data.Form;
import play.data.validation.ValidationError;
import play.i18n.Messages;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import com.pack.model.User;
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Application extends Controller {
    final static Form<User> userForm=form(User.class);
    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Welcome",userForm));
    }
}
```

i am getting a compilation `error:cannot find symbol`

```
final static Form<User> userForm=form(User.class); 
                                 ^^^^
```

Comment: `form` should be `Form`, and aren't you missing a `new` in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
final static Form<User> userForm=new Form(User.class);
```

This creates a new Form object, with parameter User.class

If it employs a factory method, instead of calling `new Form(...)`, do:

```
Form.<factorymethodname>(User.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
final static Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);
```